# Page numbers in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

*I'm gonna skip the usual rant which normally follows upon mention of the words "Word 2007"*

I have a numbered section. Which has page numbers. Then, I insert a new section break at the end of the current section ... go to page numbers, format ..., and "start at ...", and the new section then has a new page numbering (starting with some other number).

But, how do I after inserting a new section break, remove the page numbering in the new section ? If I go to remove page numbers option, Word removes the numbers from the new, but also from the old section (i.e. all of them).

*Help ... time is short ...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

> You could create a new footer for the
>   new section, and copy the content from
>   the previous footer to the new one,
>   and then delete the page numbers
>   manually for that section... It might
>   work.

Select the footer/header for the section in which you don't want page numbers, just deselect "Link to Previous" in the "Design" tab, and then now you can delete the page numbers in the section header/footer without affecting the old section.

Comment: Please, don't tell me there isn't a normal way to do that .... just awful.

Comment: actually, theres a better way. see my edit

Comment: good show ! it works!